# How to tell what invoked a trigger in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, trigger

I'm working on a legacy SQL Server application, with close to 3,000 tables and more than 10,000 stored procedures.

One of those stored procedures is deleting some needed data from a table. I don't know which one it is.

I created a trigger on the table which logs all deleted rows in another table, created just for debugging. It would be *very* helpful if the trigger could also log the *name of the stored procedure which invoked it*. Is such a thing possible in SQL Server 2008 R2 (v10.50)?

If not, is there any other information available from within a trigger which could help me identify why it was invoked?

Comment: You can use Extended Events to capture the statements that are being executed along with the object names to figure out! Use predicates to narrow down your capture.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A partial answer to your question, could be to use DBCC INPUTBUFFER, this doesn't *necessarily* give you the stored procedure that is deleting your records.  It can give you the first stored procedure called by the client, ie:

application code calls:

```
EXEC EntryStoredProc  /* this call is the one that will be identified by DBCC INPUTBUFFER */
...
/* inside EntryStoredProc */
EXEC SecondaryProc
...
/* inside SecondaryProc */
DELETE FROM [MyTable] ...
```

To add the logging to your trigger, add code similar to:

```
DECLARE @EventInfo varchar(200)
DECLARE @EventSource TABLE (EventType nvarchar(30), Parameters int, EventInfo nvarchar(4000)) 

INSERT INTO @EventSource
EXEC ('dbcc inputbuffer (' + @@spid + ') with no_infomsgs')

SELECT TOP 1 @EventInfo = SUBSTRING(APP_NAME() + '.' + ISNULL(EventInfo, ''), 0, 200) 
FROM @EventSource

INSERT INTO MyLogTable (ID, EventInfo)
SELECT d.ID, @EventInfo
FROM deleted
```

Note: This obviously has a performance impact and should not be left on your live server for a long time.

Answer (score 3):

Couple of Options:

***Option1:***

Your best option is to run a server **[side trace](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/set-up-and-schedule-a-server-side-trace)** with filtering options enabled.

This way you can narrow down the amount of data captured.

***Option2:***

Depending on the version (Enterprise), you can use **[SQL Audit](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3259/several-methods-to-collect-sql-server-stored-procedure-execution-history/)** as it allows you to track `DELETE`, `EXECUTE` and other Actions on the Object level as well. So you can filter the table that you are interested and enable the audit. Note that SQL Audit behind the covers
uses Extended Events.

***Option 3:*** *(I have not used this .. but its from msdn)*

[Light weight SQL Server procedure auditing without using SQL Server auditing version 2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/jenss/light-weight-sql-server-procedure-auditing-without-using-sql-server-auditing-version-2)

---

Another option would be to use `CONTEXT_INFO` as described in [**this**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261278/is-it-possible-for-a-trigger-to-find-the-name-of-the-stored-procedure-that-modif) answer. I dont see if this will help you as you will not be modifying legacy code.